# How to change the groupings in the stacked bar chart by using ggplot()

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a series of stacked bar chats on a cateogrical variable (customers' satisfactions on a scale of 1 to 5). I would like to display the groups from 1 to 5. However, R groups the stacked bar chart by their data labels instead of data values.

Could anyone point me where I did wrong with the chart. The ggplot aggregated the satisfaction rates ( from 1 to 5) by their data labels ( alphatically rather than from 1 to 5). How can I tell R to plot the satisfaction in a right order from 1 to 5 ( Highly Disatisfied to Highly Satisfactied)

Sorry as I am still fresh, I dont have the privileges of uploading the image. You might ahve to run the code to see the chart.

```
x8.p.m <-structure(list(Var.1 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Extremely Dis-Satistfied", 
"Highly Satisfied", "Moderately Dis-Satisfied", "Moderately Satisfied", 
"Satisfied"), class = "factor"), Var.2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("I've changed for work/ a new job/ gone on a work plan", 
"I want a phone that 2degrees doesn't offer", "I want Best Mates/ Favourites", 
"I was offered or saw a better offer on another network", "Issues with the 2degrees network (poor coverage)", 
"Other"), class = "factor"), YearQuarter = structure(c(15218, 
15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 
15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 
15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 15218, 
15218, 15218, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 
15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 
15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 
15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15309, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 
15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 
15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 
15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15400, 15492, 
15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 
15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 
15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 15492, 
15492, 15492, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 
15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 
15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 
15584, 15584, 15584, 15584, 15584), class = "Date"), value = c(70, 
20, 7, 2, 2, 54, 33, 8, 0, 4, 37, 29, 23, 11, 0, 46, 29, 18, 
4, 2, 16, 29, 26, 20, 10, 37, 20, 9, 13, 22, 66, 18, 14, 2, 0, 
65, 20, 12, 3, 0, 47, 29, 18, 4, 3, 48, 32, 16, 3, 1, 24, 25, 
19, 22, 10, 41, 14, 18, 9, 18, 66, 25, 6, 3, 0, 62, 23, 14, 1, 
0, 47, 30, 14, 8, 1, 46, 31, 16, 6, 1, 19, 27, 25, 22, 7, 34, 
15, 17, 13, 21, 68, 22, 7, 2, 1, 62, 21, 16, 1, 0, 45, 30, 18, 
5, 1, 43, 28, 22, 5, 2, 20, 23, 25, 23, 10, 36, 20, 12, 14, 19, 
60, 25, 13, 2, 0, 62, 23, 10, 6, 0, 41, 24, 26, 9, 0, 47, 31, 
16, 5, 1, 13, 29, 22, 24, 13, 28, 16, 20, 18, 18)), .Names = c("Var.1", 
"Var.2", "YearQuarter", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -150L), class = "data.frame")
> 

ggplot(data=x8.p.m, aes(x=YearQuarter, y=value, fill=Var.1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack")+facet_wrap(~Var.2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check out your factor levels:

```
levels(x8.p.m$Var.1)
```

Then check out this blog post: [LINK -click here-](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/)

PS this isn't a `ggplot2` problem as you'll read in the post.